# Deleting text between two strings using sed

Tags: sed

I am trying to delete all of the text between two strings in a number of txt files, including the strings themselves.

The strings are `SUBJECT:` and `BODY:`

This is what I have been using:

```
sed '/SUBJECT:/,/BODY:/d' *.txt
```

It appears to run without issue, but there are no changes to the files upon completion.

Comment: `sed` is not changing files. It is reading input files and writing to stdout. You might want to capture stdout.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right! Any idea how I can capture the output for each individual file? I don't want to just redirect them all into one file.

Comment: Oh. There is an `in-place` switch which I wasn't aware of. Good to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `-i` flag to modify the files in place:
`sed -i '/SUBJECT:/,/BODY:/d' *.txt`

Comment: Check `man sed` on your system. Maybe it is somewhat different implementation

Comment: It needed an extension. Thanks to you both.

Comment: sed -i is for GNU sed not posix version, use redirection in this case. Also the -i need sometimes a parameter (on Mac) sometimes as an option (most Linux common distro)